# High CPU usage with Godot tilemap

Tags: 2d, performance, tilemap, godot

I am using Godot as my game engine and I am making a basic 2D game, I have a small map with 1 Player and 5 Enemies walking around in it. The game includes some basic code for walking and shooting at enemies, so nothing too crazy. However, the game uses up to 18% of my cpu (I have an Intel Core i7 920) which it usually only does when playing big 3D games. So, what am doing wrong? I think I might be keeping track of to many enemies? I already tried the Low CPU usage option in the Godot settings, but it didnt really change anything.

Here's what I found in the profiler:

I was running for 1264 frames and it gave me this:

Script Functions - 22.79 ms

_physics_process - 80.89 ms

_physics_process - 32.96 ms

_on_Area2D_body_entered - 16.00 ms

check_input (A function checking key input) - 14.37 ms

shoot (Instancing a bullet scene and moving it) - 10.11 ms

Comment: Aren't there profilers for Godot?

Comment: Sorry, I just learned about it. Yes it has one, I dont really understand it but I will attach a screenshot of the data to the post

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. There's any number of things that *might* be impacting performance.  Making guesses (even with the help of the internet) isn't going to be nearly as productive as using tools to find the *actual* problem. The official documentation has information regarding [tools & optimizations](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/optimization/index.html) including a link to info about [improving 2D performance](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/optimization/index.html).

Comment: Thankyou, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Also, you might want to compare performance to a basic "hello world" Godot project. Sometimes there's a minimum of resources that a framework uses. I doubt that's the only thing going on here, but again, without some measurements & comparisons, it's relatively impossible to get a sense of what's going on. Using one of the starter projects will give you a baseline for comparison.

Comment: The "Low CPU usage" option is not for games. You can use Godot to make not game applications, which do not need to be drawn every frame, then "Low CPU usage" makes it so the engine only draws when the code changes something. It often does not help games. As you are aware, Godot has a profiler, there you want to see what is taking more CPU time, so you can focus on optimizing that. You may also find it useful to remove or disable things and compare what you get in the profiler. If you can edit your question with your findings, we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Thinking about your situation, it could be that you are moving the enemies on `_process`, which runs every graphics frame. And that every graphics frame might be not limited to the monitor. So you might want to enable "V Sync" and/or you might want to some code from `_process` to `_physics_process`, which works on physics frames, which you specify their rate on project settings.

Comment: Ok, thanks to your help I was able to fix it. The Level Tilemap was drawn in front of the player so everything outside the camera was drawing too. I just placed the tilemap behind the player in the node tree. I will lower the cpu usage a bit more by disabling the enemies outside the camera

Answer (score 1):

I used a Tilemap as my Level and it was put in front of the player in the node tree, so the Level outside the player camera was rendering as well. It now works just fine